# How to use code from external project in Visual studio (c#)?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, ssh

I have experience in c++ but not in c#.

I have a windows phone project going and would like to use this library:
http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

it has lots of C# source files and one Project File

After hours of googling and trying I still can't use the functions of Renci.sshnet.
I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

WP is Silverlight, so you need **SshNet Windows Phone Binary**. Did you took this one? What steps did you took to use(eg could you add a reference?).

Comment: Yeah I found out that I needed to use .dll file rather than the project. Now it works nice!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you.

First add the existing project(http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) into your same solution. Right click on the project in solution explorer and click on add reference , select the project tab. select the project you want to add.